# Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd) invoking on all folders

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Based on some condition, I am trying to copy a new email(only in inbox) to another folder. The folder is at same level as other default folders like Inbox, Outbox, Drafts. 
Below is my code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ThisAddIn.isAddInOn);

    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    items = inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
}
```

Below is code for `items_ItemAdd`:

```
void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
    Debug.WriteLine("mail");
    Debug.WriteLine(mail == null);

    if (mail!= null)
        {#code to move mail to particular folder}
```

I have not written full code of the function. Because this function is not my problem.
My issue is `items_ItemAdd` is called multiple times. For example:

1. When a new email will come
2. When a email will be moved to a another folder.

I don't want EventHandler to get invoked on the above second example. And when it is invoked second time, function `items_ItemAdd` receives and empty mail object. So I get below exception:

Exception thrown:

```
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in OutlookAddIn2.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xBDD40107): The operation failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_Body()
   at OutlookAddIn2.ThisAddIn.items_ItemAdd(Object Item)
```

is this

```
inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

pointing to all the folders?